# $.ajax Call to ColdFusion Component Outputs Text Not HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I apologize in advance if this was already answered.

My goal is to create a pagination scheme that sends variables to a query in a ColdFusion function that grabs X number of elements and displays those records on my web page without refreshing it.  So in an attempt to test the basic function of grabbing HTML content and displaying it to the screen without refreshing, I am trying to execute a simple AJAX call to a ColdFusion component, having it return a variable with HTML content, and display the formatted HTML inside a div tag on my web page.  This is based on a previous example I saw on the web where it used a cfajaxproxy instead, and while that could be my problem, I'm amazed that it's simply not doing what it's supposed to.

I have a file called testGeneration.cfm and here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <!-- call the jQuery library -->
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#loadLink").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "generateInfo.cfc?method=createHTML",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(message) {
                        $("#mydiv").html(message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="" id="loadLink">Load Query</a>
    <!-- empty div to load dynamcically generated table into -->
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see it calls the component GenerateInfo with the method CreateHTML.  Here is the code for generateInfo.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Generate HTML" output="false">

<cffunction name="createHTML" displayname="Create HTML" description="Creates HTML to output with jQuery." access="remote" output="false" returntype="string">

    <!--- SET VARIABLE TO RETURN --->
    <cfset VARIABLES.html = "">

    <!--- SAVE CONTENT --->

    <cfsavecontent variable="VARIABLES.html">
    <strong>hello world</strong>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <!--- RETURN SAVED CONTENT --->
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.html>

</cffunction>
```

Now, when I click the hyperlink, it should display the content as

**hello world**

Instead, it displays the content as

<strong>hello world</strong>

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get it to process the HTML being sent back as a return variable in a coldfusion component function?

Tony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try changing your $.ajax call to this and see if it resolves your problem:

```
$("#mydiv").load("generateInfo.cfc?method=createHTML");
```

*edit*

Based on your comment, try adding this to the cffunction tag:

```
returnFormat = "plain"
```

Comment: I replaced the ajax() code with the load() code above.  It did not resolve my problem; the HTML code still appears rather than the rendered HTML.  Anymore thoughts?

Comment: When you access generateInfo.cfc?method=createHTML directly in your browser and then view the source, is the result normal HTML text or is it escaped / encoded?

Comment: Interesting...this is what the source appears to be:

<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string><char code='0d'/><char code='0a'/><char code='09'/><char code='09'/><char code='09'/>&lt;strong&gt;hello world&lt;/strong&gt;<char code='0d'/><char code='0a'/><char code='09'/><char code='09'/></string></data></wddxPacket>

Comment: Awesome!  That did the trick!  Thank you so much Jake for your time, and now we have another tip/trick for people to check out! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was using the answer displayed here as a way to help me out since the answer was already marked and since I had the same exact problem. But the answer that was marked did not help; causing a few hours of frustration and sighs. This is because I had cfoutput within the cfcontentsave tag.

The answer below is an alternative:

The cfsavecontent was the thing that was messing things up for me. If I wanted to do a cfoutput within that area like:

```
    <cfquery datasource="whatevs" name="qry_test">
       ...
    </cfquery>

    <cfsavecontent variable="VARIABLES.html">
        <cfoutput>
            <strong>hello world</strong>
            <cfloop query="qry_test">
                #qry_test.col1#
            </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.html>
</cffunction>
```

The above would not work.

The workaround:

```
    <cfcontent type="plain/text">
        <cfoutput>
            <strong>hello world</strong>
            <cfloop query="qry_test">
                #qry_test.col1#
            </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcontent>
</cffunction>
```

Note: the returnformat attribute is not needed. Neither is a cfreturn. In addition, you could still use

```
$("#mydiv").html(message);
```

instead of the

```
$("#mydiv").load("generateInfo.cfc?method=createHTML");
```